# Should I use proxmox for this use case?

Tags: debian, proxmox

So basically I need to host an web application front and back all PHP, and also a MySQL database with HA.

There will be 2 servers on different datacenters.

And I'm thinking if we should use Proxmox with 2 VM's, one for the web application, another for the database.

Or if I should just install debian and put everything together and be done with it.

HA for the web server is being handled by an HaProxy instance that is on another server. Database HA will be handled by ProxySQL in HA ( so basically the MysQL server and ProxySQL will be in the same server ), but my applications need to know to which ProxySQL they should connect.

If I use Proxmox it's kind of simple to do this with Keepalived, because everything will use internal IP's and it's fine.

But if I use debian it will be the public ip's, and the hosting I'm using ( OVH ), has something that allows this called Floating IP's, but it takes around 5 minutes to do the switch, so it's 5 minutes that the site is down.

Using proxmox I also have other advantages I can spin up servers to do upgrades and then just switch and so on without breaking anything. Using debian directly implies reformatting the server and so on.

And of course using Proxmox will have a slight performance hit, but I think that is negligible.

There are pro/cons for either solution, and I'm not really sure which direction to go.

So virtualization or bare metal?

The servers are:

```
CPU: Xeon-E 2288G - 8c/16t
Memory: 32GB
Disks: 2× 960GB SSD NVMe - RAID 1
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: @djdomi it's not really a recommendation of a product, but more an architecture question, basically what direction should I go.

Comment: since you know the `pro/cons for either solution`, weigh them up, see what suits you and your organisation

Comment: Make yourself a favor and install everything on a simple debian server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your justification for using Proxmox here appears to be so that you can use keepalived (although I'm not sure exactly what for). That seems like massive overkill.

There are other reasons that might make sense in this context which you've hinted at.

You also mention OVH floating IPs.

This is the XY problem.

Your primary concern appears to ensuring that (at least one of) the services is available via a virtual IP.

- Virtual IPs do not work across data centres without a lot of clever routing configuration. Complexity is bad.
- Virtual IPs as a HA mechanism suck. You are relying on your system doing *something* when its in a broken state. There are complications around split brain. Its difficult to test/monitor. Ther is always an interruption to the service.
- You don't need a virtual IP - if ProxySQL (or haproxy or similar) is available / configured on each node that needs to connect to the database, and knows about all the database nodes you have HA for your database service.   For the HTTP service, the key part of HA is round-robin DNS addresses across multiple hosts. NB There is still a lot of misinfromation about rrDNS and HTTP floating about the interwebs. It deals with cases a load balancer can't and handles most of the use-cases a load balancer does.

Your biggest cost for using virtualization in a context like this is DBMS disk I/O. If mysql performance has a significant impact on the overall service performance, and your budget allows for this, then you can eliminate this issue by passing through a dedicated disk controller and storage to the DBMS VM.

Comment: you are completely right about everything. The problem that I have is in reality make a HA ( or as close as possible using ) 2 servers on OVH. I have a similar infra with proxmox and it uses Float IP's in OVH to switch between both servers, and for HA with the databases he have master-master replication with a Virtual IP so that all our applications can connect to the correct server. ( and as you can imagine we already had problems with that, because one of the MySQL servers went out of sync ).

But in my head it doesn't make sense to install ProxySQL or whatever on every node that - Part 1

Comment: connects to the database. In the current infra we have like 15 VM's that connect all to the same MySQL server, installing ProxySQL on each one seem crazy ( although it makes sense in my head, no more virtual IP's and so on ). In our case virtual Ip's work ok between datacenters they switch and everything works correctly ( or al least seems to ).

But for my case, since it's only one application that needs to connect to the database, and it's only one VM, installing SqlProxy on every node seems to do the trick, no more VIp's for anything.

Thank you!

Comment: And btw, I'm only creating this new infra because of DBMS disk I/O. Because the old infra is on Sata HDD and everything is super slowing down.